# How to remove Run As Administration

Tags: c#, user-permissions, administrator

I have a C# application and I did create a setup project for it.
The tool is working fine and also the setup but I have only one problem which is I need to run the tool as admin every time I want to run it!

Comment: Does this only happen when you install the tool or also when you copy the exe from the build output and execute it directly?

Comment: Could it be "Run As Administrator" is there for a reason?

Comment: What does the tool do? Did you change the manifest to require admin mode?

Comment: What is the name of your tool?

Comment: I just try to install the tool , and btw i have admin premonitions !

Comment: Could you please answer the following: Does your tool do something that would require admin rights (i.e. write to protected locations, access system registry, etc.)? Also: Does Windows show "Run as Admin" if you run the exe directly or only if you use a link to the exe?

Comment: @Ateeq you application doesn't run in an elevated state (as administrator) even though you have the correct permission to do so, before you actually tell it to do so.

Comment: @Ateeq To clarify the question: Does your application prompt for admin rights and you do not want it to do so, or do you **want** your application to automatically prompt for admin rights, but you have to right-click and select "Run as Administrator" to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add app.manifest to your exe project and set following

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```